# Nodejs web app authentication allowanonymous or bypassauthorization filter?

Tags: node.js, authentication

I want to implement an authentication logic similar to the asp.net mvc's allowanonymous attribute.

In node app I have code like this

```
var authChecker = function(req, res, next){
if (req.session.user 
    && req.session.user.loggedIn) {
    next();
}
else {
    res.redirect('/login');
}   
}
app.use(authChecker);

//this path should be allowed for anonymous access
app.get('/public', function(req, res) { 

});

//this path is checked globally
app.get('/private', function(req, res) { 

});
```

but I chould'nt figure out how to create a filter for the paths that I want to make accessible with out login...

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `use`ing `authChecker` globally, just use it in each route you want to protect.

```
var authChecker = function(req, res, next){
if (req.session.user 
    && req.session.user.loggedIn) {
    next();
}
else {
    res.redirect('/login');
}   
}


//this path should be allowed for anonymous access
app.get('/public', function(req, res) { 

});

//this path is checked globally
app.get('/private', authChecker, function(req, res) { 

});
```

Comment: the security best practice says that we should make all the app private and just bypass authorization for the necassary pages...

Comment: a developer may forget to add authchecker it is a problem, but if someone forgets to add bypassautorization or allowanonymous thing it is not a problem...